# Car banner animation website

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I got this car link website from the internet http://www.toyota.com.au/yaris/accessories

What I want to ask is. Which programming language that the website made for that animation? Is it Css or HTML or JQUERY ? I saw in page source but I can not define it. I want to make the animation banner like those website. That's why I want to explore on how to make it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know which question type is it. But I really want to know. Do you have idea which type of question should be? So I will change it.

Comment: Javascript, probably flavored with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**They have used some jquery/javascript plugins for this banner animation..**
Here are few usefull links for the same..

1. http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/360-Interactive-Product-Viewer-Plugin-With-JQuery-Angle-View/
2. http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel#demo
3. http://www.mathieusavard.info/threesixty/demo.html

Comment: thank you so much for your information

Comment: You are welcome :)